# Long click event doesn't fire when also listening for touch

Tags: c#, android, events, touch, long-click

Is there a good way to listen for both `Touch` and `LongClick` events?

When my touch event fires, the resulting actions are all in a different thread, so code isn't running in the UI thread, but the long click event still doesn't seem to fire. This is in Xamarin, if that makes a difference.

Documentation for [OnTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) and for [OnLongClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html)

Is there a workaround for this?